# The edit button is deleting from the database instead of saving to it MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have posted the relevant code to this issue below. My problem is, let's say, the database is displaying NA, I want to edit it and put in 1.1, or some number. Instead of updating and saving this new number, it deletes NA and does not update or save anything, so I know it is doing something, but I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. If I change the type in the model to int or object, it gives an error for conversion to string. Can someone help please? Thank you!

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit ()
    {
        return View ();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyIssue issues)
    {
        var model = new Test.Models.Tables();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(issues).State = EntityState.Modified;
            issues.Number = model.Number;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(issues);
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
   public class Tables: DbContext
   {
       public string Number { get; set; }
   }
}
```

View:

```
<td>
   @if (issue.Number != null)
   { 
      @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => issue.Number)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => issue.Number)
      <text>|</text>
      <h5 id="editclass">
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Page1", new { id = issue.Number })
      </h5>


    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true) {

       <fieldset>
       @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => issue.Number)

       <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => issue.Number)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => issue.Number)
       </div>

       <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
       </p>

       </fieldset>
       }
   }
}
</td>
```

Comment: So are you saying your record is still there, but the value of `Number` column is updated to `null` ?

Comment: Yes, you got it. :)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: model.Number will always be empty in above case, is it? So you are updating empty value to database. Is that the problem? If you remove that line, it should work as you expect IMO

Comment: Your code is confusing. What is the model in the view? You have shown a `Table` class but the model in the POST method is `MyIssue`. You have a hidden input for `issue.Number` followed by a textbox for the same property (the `DefaultModelBinder` will ignore the second one so the value that is posted will always be the initial value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume that the code you shown is inside a loop where `issue` is the loop iterator variable. So razor will generate an input field with name "issue.Number". When the form is submitted, model binder cannot bind this form value to the `Number` property of your MyIssue object ! So it gets the default null value and your code is assigning the `null`  value as the Number property and saving it.

You should generate an input field with name="Number". You may use the Html.TextBox helper method to do so.

```
@foreach (var issue in SomeCollection)
{
   <tr>
         <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
               <!-- Other fields also goes here -->
               @Html.TextBox("Number",issue.Number)
               <input type="submit" />
            }
         </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm implementing this incorrectly, but it's still giving a null.

Comment: Check the view source and make sure that your inout field name is "Number". It should work then when you post the form.